# Why does Database.Query() return null, when empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4, mono

I'm trying to run some ASP.NET code on my webserver, which has Mono 3.10.0 and ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020 installed.

The code in question is this:

```
var db = Database.Open("myMySQLdatabase");
var q1 = db.Query(@"SELECT id FROM ph_conditions WHERE conditionName = '"+newCondName+"'");
if(q1==null || q1.Count() == 0){
    //
}
```

When db.Query() is run, and if there are no matches in my database, it returns "null", instead of what I would be expecting, which is an IEnumerable list of size 0. Why is this the case?

If there are matches, then it behaves as expected.

Right now, to get around it the null errors, I include a check to see if the query is null or not, but it should always return a list of some kind, even if it is empty, right?

Comment: What is `Database.Query`? It's neither EF nor subsonic, isn't it? Maybe it's just what your framework does.

Comment: It's a method from the [WebMatrix.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.query%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the WebMatrix.Data that comes with Mono 3.10.0 isn't exactly like it's Windows counterpart, in which that it returns "null" if a query has no results.

So to remedy this, I added a line in the Database.cs to return an empty List and recompiled the WebMatrix.Data.dll